# Referencing if/then statements with a model?

Tags: python, django

I have a site for my students where I have pulled in a bunch of information from different websites they use for instruction. I want to be able to award 'badges' if they meet certain criteria, like reading 50 books, or spending 100 minutes practicing math, etc. That data is stored as objects in different models on my site.

I can't figure out how to cleanly make different badge objects with unique requirements for unlocking each badge without being incredibly repetitive.

My basic model:

```
class Sticker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255,)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='stickers')
    #requirements = ?
```

I'd like to be able to easily add badges with just a line of code like this as the requirement:

```
if books_read >= 50: 
    return True
```

Part of the complexity is that there are a lot of different types of requirements with different models for all the different "Stickers" they can earn.

I tried [Django Badgify](https://github.com/ulule/django-badgify) but ran into a couple issues. My students aren't actual Django Users, and I don't know how to separate that part out, as the script is far more complex than I'm currently able to modify with my skillset.

What's the best way to work in a bit of code like this? Is there a way I can run code that's entered into a TextField? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make a badge per achievement then you could try this... (everything I give is an example)

1. Check the perquisites
2. If they match then proceed to 4
3. If not match then check next achievement and go to 1
4. Give them the badge!

You need to make that same script for every achievement.

Im not entirely sure about the modules functions you are using but I would imagine that you need to check each user account separately per achievement.